# Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{e^{i{\frac{\pi}{n}}}}{\sqrt n}}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{e^{i{\frac{\pi}{n}}}}{\sqrt n}}$$
First I check whether it converges absolutely (in which case in converges).
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{e^{i{\frac{\pi}{n}}}}{\sqrt n}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{1}{\sqrt n}} \times |e^{i{\frac{\pi}{n}}}| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{1}{\sqrt n}} \times 1
$$
Since ${\frac{1}{\sqrt n}}$ converges then I'd say the whole series converges.
But the answer is that it doesn't converge.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $1/\sqrt{n}$ doesn't converge.

Comment: How would you prove that the series of $n^{-1/2}$ converges? Any way, if your series comverged, then its real part would; however the real part is equivalent to $n^{-1/2} >0$ thus it will diverge.

Comment: $1/\sqrt{n}$ converges, but the relevant thing is $\sum 1/\sqrt{n}$ diverges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt n}$ diverges. Therefore, your argument is flawed.

On the other hand$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{e^{i\frac\pi n}}{\sqrt n}\right)=\frac{\cos\left(\frac\pi n\right)}{\sqrt n}\geqslant\frac1{2\sqrt n}$$if $n$ is large enough. Therefore, yes, your series diverges.